# C# Unicode Parts in Console string

Tags: c#, android, input, encoding, adb

I have a code:

```
string command = @"adb -s 127.0.0.1:62001 install \"D:\Рабочий_стол\Facebook.apk\"";
// clear string: adb -s 127.0.0.1:62001 install "D:\Рабочий_стол\Facebook.apk"

Process p = new Process();
            
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            
p.Start();
            
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);

p.StandardInput.Flush();
p.StandardInput.Close();
p.WaitForExit();
            
return p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

In output:

(c) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation). ‚бҐ Їа ў  § йЁйҐ­л.

C:>adb -s 127.0.0.1:62001 install "D:\Рабочий_стол\Facebook.apk"
Performing Streamed Install

C:>

But nothing starts :(

if i run manually this line ("D:\Рабочий_стол\Facebook.apk") in the console - works fine

Problem with "Рабочий_стол"

also i tried a simpler command: D:\Рабочий_стол\Task.txt - the same problem

Can be copied the file, for example, to the root of the D drive where there are no Russian characters in path... but its no good :)

I'l tried many options with encodings and StreamWriters, but nothing work fine in my situation

Comment: are you expecting that the apk installed will start?

Comment: Adjust your console encoding to avoid [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) (example in Python): `'Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв'.encode( 'cp1251').decode( 'cp866')` returns `'Корпорация Майкрософт'` and vice versa: `'Корпорация Майкрософт'.encode( 'cp866').decode( 'cp1251')` yields `'Љ®аЇ®а\xa0жЁп Њ\xa0©Єа®б®дв'`. I'd try `chcp 65001` (==`utf-8`) before running the code